# understanding single responsibility principal SRP in clean code example

Tags: oop, design-patterns, coding-style, single-responsibility-principle

currently i'm reading the clean code Book of Uncle Bob,in the function section when looking to the following example:-

```
public Money calculatePay(Employee e)
throws InvalidEmployeeType {
    switch (e.type) {
        case COMMISSIONED:
            return calculateCommissionedPay(e);
        case HOURLY:
            return calculateHourlyPay(e);
        case SALARIED:
            return calculateSalariedPay(e);
        default:
            throw new InvalidEmployeeType(e.type);
    }
}
```

Uncle Bob said:-

> There are several problems with this function. First, it’s large, and
>   when new employee types are added, it will grow. Second, it very
>   clearly does more than one thing. Third, it violates the Single
>   Responsibility Principle7 (SRP) because there is more than one reason
>   for it to change. Fourth, it violates the Open Closed Principle8 (OCP)
>   because it must change whenever new types are added

he states a solution as following:-

```
public abstract class Employee {
    public abstract boolean isPayday();
    public abstract Money calculatePay();
    public abstract void deliverPay(Money pay);
}
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
public interface EmployeeFactory {
    public Employee makeEmployee(EmployeeRecord r) throws InvalidEmployeeType;
}
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
public class EmployeeFactoryImpl implements EmployeeFactory {
    public Employee makeEmployee(EmployeeRecord r) throws InvalidEmployeeType {
        switch (r.type) {
            case COMMISSIONED:
                return new CommissionedEmployee(r);
            case HOURLY:
                return new HourlyEmployee(r);
            case SALARIED:
                return new SalariedEmploye(r);
            default:
                throw new InvalidEmployeeType(r.type);
        }
    }
}
```

I can not fully understand the idea from the example and there is some question in my head i can not find answers to :-

1- in first code when new employee is added it will grow. true but also this occurs in the solution so what is the difference ?
2- how the first example does more than one thing . it only calculate payment "functions at the same level of abstraction" notice that if we consider throw error is another thing to do , the solution does it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
First, it’s large, and when new employee types are added, it will grow.
```

You're right, the solution doesn't really make the overall code size shorter and when a new employee type is added, it will still grow overall.

```
Second, it very clearly does more than one thing.
```

The original both handles dispatching to the correct payment calculation function and calculates the payment.  The proposed solution addresses this.  `HourlyEmployee.calculatePay()` now calculates pay only for an `HourlyEmployee`, etc.  `EmployeeFactoryImpl` handles the dispatch based on the `Employee` implementation it returns.

```
Third, it violates the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) because there is more than one reason for it to change.
```

The original `calculatePay` needs to change if the pay calculation logic needs to change.  It also needs to change if a new employee type is added.  The solution does not require a change to `calculatePay` when a new employee type is added.  Thus there is only a single responsibility and a single reason to change.

```
Fourth, it violates the Open Closed Principle (OCP) because it must change whenever new types are added
```

Going back to `1`, the overall code length will still change when a new employee type is added.  However, only the part related to dealing with employee types has to change.  The code devoted to calculating pay doesn't need to change at all.  Thus the part that needs to be extended is open, and the part that is unrelated to the extension is closed.

Comment: if we consider that calculate commission-hour-salary is doing more than one thing the i notice that they are all functions "in first code" (at the same level of abstraction) so they do one thing , Uncle Bob said that "If a function does only those steps that are one level below the stated name of the
function, then the function is doing one thing" Clean Code page 36

Comment: of course after applying the solution the calculatePay function will not need to be changed  instead changes will be applied to factory class EmployeeFactoryImpl, is that will be accepted ?

Comment: @MostafaDarwish the original doesn't do only steps 1 level below the name of the function.  In addition to calculating pay, `calculatePay` also handles dispatching to the correct payment calculation function.  As the example shows, this is not "one level below the stated name of the function".  We can see this clearly since the `EmployeeFactoryImpl`, which knows nothing about any of the logic to calculate pay, can still properly handle the dispatch.

Comment: ok let's pronounce it as 'TO':-"To calculate Pay we should select type of employee, and to select Type of employee we switch over employee type and if it's commission we calculate commissioned...".You are right ,they are not at the same level

Answer (score 0):

1) More code is harder to understand, debug and maintain. Sure, the example isn't that big, but you get the point. Keeping classes small and to the point aids maintainability, extensibility and re-usability. What's more, if you change the code, adding a new section for the new employee type, you potentially break the old code.

2) The logic in each calculation is going to be different. Therefore, the class is doing three different things. If you split each calculation into its own class, you get the benefits mentioned in 1 plus the solution is much more testable.